# Running applications do not appear

Tags: 17.04, taskbar, application-switcher

In Ubuntu, any running applications (or rather, their (main?) windows) are usually shown in at least two places (please excuse the possibly incorrect terminology - feel free to insert the actual terms via edits):

- the "task bar" on the side
- the "window switcher" popup when pressing Alt + Tab

Since very recently (possibly, but not definitely since the upgrade to Ubuntu 17.04 a few days ago?), none of this happens any more for some applications. Their icons will just not appear in the described places.

In particular, I notice this when launching [MonoDevelop](http://www.monodevelop.com/) - the application works fine, but I cannot switch back to it once it is in the background, other than by minimizing/resizing the other windows.

**Is there any way to "recover/reset" the "task bar" and "switcher" so that it reloads the list of running applications?** Of course, a system reboot might do, but as always, it's a nuisance to do that when I notice the issue in the middle of my work.

Comment: If you know the task bar's name or PID you could kill/restart it... sounds like a bug though